# Control Internet connection data

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming, port, communication

I want to control internet connection programmatically, (I use Visual Studio .net (C#)). I want to process all the requests that are sent to the internet.

For example, if a user on any browser type "google.com", I want to get this request before it's sent to the internet.

Simply, it's a process that Windows uses to send and retrieve data from a communication port, please do any one have a simple article that explain this process, also does any one have an idea how to control the data flow on communication ports using dot net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out how [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), a transparent proxy that automatically adds itself to the WININET chain so that it can see every request being made, works.

According to [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446.aspx) article:

> ...the program registers itself as the
>   system proxy for Microsoft Windows
>   Internet Services (WinInet), the HTTP
>   layer used by Internet Explorer,
>   Microsoft Office, and many other
>   products.

Additionally, take a look at the answers to this question - [How to create a simple Proxy in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c).