# System.Net.ProtocolViolationException Exception C# Post and Getresponse

Tags: c#, .net, post

For the below code I am getting following error,

> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: You must provide a request body
>   if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling
>   [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse.

I am not sure why this error is thrown, any comments or suggestions would be helpful

```
                 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://");

                 // Set the ContentType property. 
                 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                 // Set the Method property to 'POST' to post data to the URI.
                 request.Method = "POST";
                 request.KeepAlive = true;
                 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                 request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                 // Start the asynchronous operation.    
                 request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);

                 // Keep the main thread from continuing while the asynchronous
                 // operation completes. A real world application
                 // could do something useful such as updating its user interface. 
                 allDone.WaitOne();

                 // Get the response.
                 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                 Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                 StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                 string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                 Console.WriteLine(responseString);
                 Console.ReadLine();
                 // Close the stream object.
                 streamResponse.Close();
                 streamRead.Close();

                 // Release the HttpWebResponse.
                 response.Close();





    private static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation.
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);



        // Convert the string into a byte array.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Write to the request stream.
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        allDone.Set();
    }
```

Now I modified my code for using HttpClient but does not work,

```
    public static async void PostAsync(String postData)
    {

        try
        {
            // Create a New HttpClient object.
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://", new StringContent(postData));
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method in following line 
            // string body = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're defeating the purpose of async by sleeping until it's finished.  You should make your code actually asynchronous.  Consider using `Task`s.

Comment: Better yet, switch to `HttpClient`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying Http Request InputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447589/copying-http-request-inputstream)

Comment: How are you setting the "postData" variable? in the ReadCallBack method?

Comment: I am setting value of postData variable before invoking POST Http requst

Comment: I have modified my code for using HttpClient, but it goes into infinite wait state and the Http Post request is not being invoked

Comment: Are you really trying to get from `"http://"`? Or is that just there as an example? Your problem might be related to the special status of `async void` methods. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12144077/56778

Comment: Which server are you making the requests to? (IIS, Apache etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the error is due to you mixing asynchronous and synchronous operations. Documentation for [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx) says:

> Your application cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous methods for a particular request. If you call the BeginGetRequestStream method, you must use the BeginGetResponse method to retrieve the response.

Your code calls `BeginGetRequestStream`, but it calls `GetResponse`.

What I think is happening is that it calls `BeginGetRequestStream`, which starts the asynchronous writing to the request stream, but on the main thread it calls `GetResponse` concurrently. So it's attempting to make the request before the request is formatted.

Study the example in the linked MSDN topic and modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider the possibility for inserted a proxy?

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://[proxyaddress]"  bypassonlocal="True"  usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This works for my code and resolved the same issue, check in your net.