# System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() error "You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse."

Tags: asp.net, system.net.httpwebrequest, webresponse, maxrequestlength

I have a method that uploads files to our server. I'm seeing the error in the title when trying to upload a large file. I've tried increasing maxRequestLength from 35480 KB in web.config but I'm still seeing the error.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="3548000" executionTimeout="1000" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
```

I've also tried making the request within a using statement as mentioned in this post [System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297612/system-net-protocolviolationexception-you-must-write-contentlength-bytes-to-the) to no avail. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webrequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webrequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        webrequest.Method = "POST";

        // Build up the post message header
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("--"); sb.Append(boundary); sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""); sb.Append(fileFormName); 
        sb.Append("\"; filename=\""); sb.Append(Path.GetFileName(uploadfile)); sb.Append("\""); sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("Content-Type: "); sb.Append("application/octet-stream"); sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("\r\n");            

        string postHeader = sb.ToString();
        byte[] postHeaderBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postHeader);
        // Build the trailing boundary string as a byte array. ensuring the boundary appears on a line by itself
        byte[] boundaryBytes =  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        string strRead = "";
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        Stream requestStream = null;
        WebResponse responce = null;
        StreamReader responseStream = null;

        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileStream(uploadfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            long length = postHeaderBytes.Length + fileStream.Length + boundaryBytes.Length;
            webrequest.ContentLength = length;

            using (requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                //requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
                // Write out our post header
                requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length);
                // Write out the file contents
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)fileStream.Length))];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) { requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); }
                // Write out the trailing boundary
                requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);

                responce = webrequest.GetResponse();
            }
            responseStream = new StreamReader(responce.GetResponseStream());

            strRead = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                     // handle error
        }
        finally
        {
            if( fileStream != null ) fileStream.Close();
            if( requestStream != null ) requestStream.Close();
            if( responseStream != null ) responseStream.Close();
            if( responce != null ) responce.Close();
        }
        return strRead;
```

Comment: have you tried something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data/2996904#2996904

Comment: maybe share the code that generates all those byte arrays? I feel like I am missing something...

Comment: updated post to include construction

Comment: The ContentLength property of webrequest is there. Perhaps it's not finished writing by the time webrequest.GetResponse() is called

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by setting maxAllowedContentLength in system.webServer. [Maximum request length exceeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded/12496077#12496077)