# How to write a proxy in C#?

Tags: c#, proxy

i want to write a simple proxy. I don't know what a proxy is. Someone please explain and give a simple http proxy code ?

Comment: my friend asked to write one for him.

Comment: @user3281496 said : "Can you please share the web proxy code in C# if you got it to work?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following links
Proxy is a software that is between the client and the server. For example the web browser requests for a web page the requests passes to the proxy then the proxy request the page and sends it back to the web browser.

[How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket_members(v=VS.90).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Read [`RFC2068`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) and learn about [socket programming in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) for a good overview of the proxy pattern. If you're talking about proxy servers then Wikipedia is still your friend - a proxy server is a special case of the pattern.

Comment: thanks. can you explain more about proxy server

Comment: A proxy server is just something that sits between the client and the real server and forwards messages on. It may or may not do some processing of the messages, depending on your design goals. Proxy servers are often used to provide a path through a firewall, or to provide a local cache.