# How can I get the url of all tabs opened in a browser?

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows form app to keep track of the urls opened in my browser but a browser may contain many tabs.

How can i get the urls in all tabs opened at the same time using c#?

Comment: What browser?  What have you tried?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307946/get-the-urls-of-opened-tabs-in-browser) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814027/how-can-i-get-urls-of-open-pages-from-chrome-and-firefox) are some examples.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the URl From Firefox and Opera :

   ```
   DdeClient dde = new DdeClient(browser, "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
   dde.Connect();
   string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
   string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   dde.Disconnect();
   return text[0].Substring(1);
   ```