# Close a single tab in browser using windows application c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser, window-handles

My requirement is very simple. Trying from morning. Couldn't figure it out. Help me out to solve this.

I am opening a google page from my windows application in a button click using Process.start(). It opens in mozila browser. The browser contains 3 other tabs. In another button click i want to close the opened google page. But browser should not be closed and it should retain the other tabs which are already opened. Is there any simple way to do it ?

Forgive me for my english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i don't have the comments previlages but this is same in somwhat manner it might help you [acessing browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307946/get-the-urls-of-opened-tabs-in-browser)