# Get URL from Opera browser

Tags: c#, opera

I am trying to get URL from Opera browser, I assumed it is the same as for Chrome but I was wrong since it doesn't work this way.

whatever I have done so far is:

```
    public static string GetURL(IntPtr intPtr, string programName, out string url)
    {
        string temp = null;
            if (programName.Equals("opera"))
        {
        //    // there are always multiple opera processes, so we have to loop through all of them to find the
        //    // process with a Window Handle and an automation element of name "Address and search bar"
          /*  string x = "";
            DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("opera", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
            try
            {
                //temp := RequestData('0xFFFFFFFF');
                dde.Connect();
                string url1 = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
                string[] text = url1.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                dde.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                x = "failed";
             }
*/



            Process[] procsOpera = Process.GetProcessesByName("opera");
            foreach (Process opera in procsOpera)
            {
                // the chrome process must have a window
                if (opera.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
               {
                      continue;
                }

                // find the automation element
                AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(opera.MainWindowHandle);
                AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));

                // if it can be found, get the value from the URL bar
                if (elmUrlBar != null)
                {
                    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                    if (patterns.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                        temp = val.Current.Value.ToString();
                        url = val.Current.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = "";
                        url = "";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = "";
                    url = "";
                }
            }
        }
        url = temp;
        return temp;
    }
```

I have tried it with both NDDE client and automation element, but both are failed :(
I think in automation element the problem is in this line

```
AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
```

Perhaps for opera it isn't `"Address and search bar"` can some 1 help me to solve the issue please?

**NOTE:** There are couple question where chrome and opera tagged but there is no Opera working answer inside on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Inspect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which offers the same functionality as UISpy to get the AutomationId from the Opera UI. I assume the reason it is not working is because it is named differently in Opera.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! the element I was looking for called "`Address field"` if some1 will need it in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the `NDde dll`. After adding a reference simply just copy this code to where you want to get the url.

NDde DLL Download : http://ndde.codeplex.com/

```
DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("opera", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
dde.Connect();
string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
dde.Disconnect();
```

If you want to get firefox data simply change the `opera` to `firefox`

```
DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
dde.Connect();
string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
dde.Disconnect();
```

In a function

```
private string GetBrowserURL(string browser) {
    try {
        DdeClient dde = new DdeClient(browser, "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
        dde.Connect();
        string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
        string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        dde.Disconnect();
        return text[0].Substring(1);
    } catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it (it is commented in my question) but it just doesn't work for Opera however I do using it for firefox and IE. thanks for answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

1. Get Process id for opera:

   ```
   public static void GetOperaURL()
   {
      Process[] OProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("opera");
      string url = null;
      foreach (Process proc in OProcesses)
      {
          if (proc.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
          {
               url = getOperaUrlFromProcess(proc);
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use automation element for determining URL

   `private static string getOperaUrlFromProcess(Process proc)
   {
       // find the automation element
       AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

       // manually walk through the tree, searching using TreeScope.Descendants is too slow (even if it's more reliable)
       AutomationElement elmUrlBar = null;
       try
       {
           var elm1 = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Browser container"));
           if (elm1 == null) { return null; } 
           elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address field"));
       }
       catch
       {
           // Chrome has probably changed something, and above walking needs to be modified. :(
           // put an assertion here or something to make sure you don't miss it
           return null;
       }

       // make sure it's valid
       if (elmUrlBar == null)
       {
           // it's not..
           return null;
       }

       // there might not be a valid pattern to use, so we have to make sure we have one
       AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
       if (patterns.Length == 1)
       {
           string ret = "";
           try
           {
               ret = ((ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0])).Current.Value;
           }
           catch { }
           if (ret != "")
           {
               return ret;
           }
           return null;
       }
       return null;
   }`

Answer (score 1):

Changed your function and made it simple as possible. Works with the current Opera version 47.0

```
public static string GetOperaURL()
    {
        string url = "";

        Process[] procsOpera = Process.GetProcessesByName("opera");
        foreach (Process opera in procsOpera)
        {
            // the chrome process must have a window
            if (opera.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // find the automation element
            AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(opera.MainWindowHandle);
            AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address field"));

            // if it can be found, get the value from the URL bar
            if (elmUrlBar == null) continue;

            AutomationPattern pattern = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns().FirstOrDefault(wr=>wr.ProgrammaticName == "ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern");

            if (pattern == null) continue;

            ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(pattern);
            url = val.Current.Value;
            break;
        }

        return url;
    }
```