# Get URL from browser (GoogleChrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge, Brave) in WPF Desktop App

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, url, browser

I have created a WPF desktop application. This detects active window, if active window is browser, app gets URL of current process.(the function is written below). This method 50% working and 50% not.
means(some sites are not tracing, in some browsers not working accurately). also it takes some time and CPUusage.

I have checked older threads related to this.

[Get URL from browser to C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579649/get-url-from-browser-to-c-sharp-application?answertab=modifieddesc#)

[Get Firefox URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430614/get-firefox-url)

https://itecnote.com/tecnote/c-retrieve-current-url-from-c-windows-forms-application/

[Get URL from Opera browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968177/get-url-from-opera-browser)

I have used `**DdeClient **`

```
 public static string GetFirefoxURL()
  {
      try
      {
          DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
          dde.Connect();
          string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
          string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
          dde.Disconnect();
          return text[0].Substring(1);
      }
      catch
      {
          return null;
      }
  }
```

Here I am using `**UIAutomation**`.

```
// some code
           var hWnd = NativeMethods.GetForegroundWindow();
           var process = NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID);

// and the given below function calling for tracing url

public static string GetUrlFromProcess(Process process)
 {
     using (process)
     {
         try
         {
                  CUIAutomation _automation = new CUIAutomation();
                  IUIAutomationElement elm = _automation.ElementFromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
                  IUIAutomationCondition Cond = _automation.CreatePropertyCondition(30003, 50004);
                  IUIAutomationElementArray elm2 = elm.FindAll(TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants, Cond);

                  if (elm2 != null)
                  {
                      for (int i = 0; i < elm2.Length; i++)
                      {
                          IUIAutomationElement elm3 = elm2.GetElement(i);
                          IUIAutomationValuePattern val = (IUIAutomationValuePattern)elm3.GetCurrentPattern(10002);
                          if (val != null)
                          {
                              if (val.CurrentValue != "")
                              {
                                  return val.CurrentValue;
                              }
                          }
                          return "";
                      }
                  }
                  return "";
         }

         catch
         { return "something went wrong"; }
     }
 }
```

```
public static string GetFirefoxUrl(Process process)
  {
      if (process == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("process");

      if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
          return null;

      AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
      if (element == null)
          return null;

      AutomationElement doc = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Document));
      if (doc == null)
          return null;
      var d = ((ValuePattern)doc.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern));
      var c = d.Current;
      var b = c.Value;
      Debug.Write("url ff: " + b);
      return b;
// this returns first tab's url of firefox instead of active tab.
  }
```

unable to achieve desired functionality.

I am expecting that it trace URL from any website which is opened in any browser, if youtube is playing in full screen also get its URL.
cpu usage and time to complete this process is also important.

*anybody replies are highly appreciated.
thanks in advance.*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Trace URL from browser from C# desktop application efficiently and accurately. this was solved around 10years ago but with the passage of updates in browsers and deprecation of some libraries its unable for me to trace URL from browser by using C# desktop application.