# refresh Tab in Browser if already open, using a c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am opening an html file in my application like

```
string browserPath = GetBrowserPath();
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(browserPath);
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + path_htmlFile + "\"";
process.Start();
```

But if i call it again, i get only a new tab in my browser instead of refreshing the first one.
How could i solve this?

I am using c# with visual studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate the browser application followed by sending refresh keys to it. One way of achieving this is to use the [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx) Windows API function and the [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) method.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var browserPath = @"chrome";
        RefreshBrowserTab(browserPath);
    }

    private static void RefreshBrowserTab(string browserPath)
    {
        var processName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(browserPath);
        var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        foreach (var process in processes)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
        }
        SendKeys.SendWait("^r");
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
}
```

Alternatively, you can achieve this using Windows Scripting Host's WshShellObject.AppActivate and WshShellObject.SendKeys methods. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahcz2kh6(v=vs.84).aspx.

Comment: refreshing works fine, but how do i recognize if file is already open?

Comment: i found a way like "if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains("html-title"))" but this will only work if the file is open in the current tab and the command "SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);" refreshes all tab not only the required one

Comment: This post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814027/how-can-i-get-urls-of-open-pages-from-chrome-and-firefox - lists some ways to get URLs open in the browser. You can check if your URL is already open by comparing against these and activate the one that matches.