# How to get current URL from google chrome version 45 in C#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I need to get the current url in google chrome version 45.

I was searching and get some pages:

- [How can I get URLs of open pages from Chrome and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814027/how-can-i-get-urls-of-open-pages-from-chrome-and-firefox)
- [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp)

I need a recently solution .the two lasts solution work correctly in previous chrome versions

Comment: What's wrong with the provided search results?. Please, expand your question with more details.

Comment: my previous search work correctly in previous versions

Comment: You should try add some code sample to your question. Read the [Stack Overflow's Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and use the search results that you provided for update your question. This changes will help you to get addequate answers.

Comment: Yes, since chrome 38 or 40 something's changed..

Comment: I make a chrome extenstion to solve this

Answer (score 2):

Try this starting for version 38 or 40 to 45.x (at the moment of writing)

```
public string GetChormeURL(string ProcessName)
        {
            string ret = "";
            Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
            foreach (Process proc in procs)
            {
                // the chrome process must have a window
                if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                //         new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"));
                // find the automation element
                AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);


            // manually walk through the tree, searching using TreeScope.Descendants is too slow (even if it's more reliable)
            AutomationElement elmUrlBar = null;
            try
            {
                // walking path found using inspect.exe (Windows SDK) for Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m (currently the latest stable)
                // Inspect.exe path - C://Program files (X86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/x64
                var elm1 = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Google Chrome"));
                if (elm1 == null) { continue; } // not the right chrome.exe
                var elm2 = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetLastChild(elm1); // I don't know a Condition for this for finding
                var elm3 = elm2.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ""));
                var elm4 = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetNextSibling(elm3); // I don't know a Condition for this for finding
                var elm5 = elm4.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ToolBar));
                var elm6 = elm5.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ""));
                elmUrlBar = elm6.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
            }
            catch
            {
                // Chrome has probably changed something, and above walking needs to be modified. :(
                // put an assertion here or something to make sure you don't miss it
                continue;
            }

            // make sure it's valid
            if (elmUrlBar == null)
            {
                // it's not..
                continue;
            }

            // elmUrlBar is now the URL bar element. we have to make sure that it's out of keyboard focus if we want to get a valid URL
            if ((bool)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.HasKeyboardFocusProperty))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // there might not be a valid pattern to use, so we have to make sure we have one
            AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
            if (patterns.Length == 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    ret = ((ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0])).Current.Value;
                    return ret;
                }
                catch { }
                if (ret != "")
                {
                    // must match a domain name (and possibly "https://" in front)
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(ret, @"^(https:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*$"))
                    {
                        // prepend http:// to the url, because Chrome hides it if it's not SSL
                        if (!ret.StartsWith("http"))
                        {
                            ret = "http://" + ret;
                        }
                        return ret;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/995898/how-to-get-URL-form-any-web-browser-like-firefox-i

Comment: now I work  to solve this problem . I decide  to create chrome extension make the same

Comment: where did it fail for you? I have it plugged in my project (though adapted ofcourse) and it detects chrome 45 fine? What system are you on?

Comment: ooh.so sorry > my system is windows 7

Comment: should work on win 7 too - as it's tested there.. mind that it may not work anymore for chrome versions above 45.. these things change rapidly. I have implemented a strategy pattern for this, an based on the browser's version a specific algorithm (strategy) fires.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
            {
                // the chrome process must have a window
                if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // find the automation element
                AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);
                AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));

                // if it can be found, get the value from the URL bar
                if (elmUrlBar != null)
                {
                    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                    if (patterns.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Chrome URL found: " + val.Current.Value);
                        listbox.Items.Add(val.Current.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that getting the Element by Name "Address and search bar" is localized and therefore only working on english chrome / Windows. Get the right localized name with inspect.exe. For German that's: "Adress- und Suchleiste"