# c# Getting Chrome URL's from all tab

Tags: c#, google-chrome, monitoring, ui-automation

hi i want to get URL from browsers and for chrome i used these and the is not working getting null exception  i think chrome has changed something.. getting error on   elm4 == null.

using UIAutomation i searched more and all the example are not working ...

refrences:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21799588/5096993
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39bf60a8-2bdc-4aa0-96fb-08dca49cdb06/c-get-all-chrome-urls-opened?forum=csharpgeneral

```
else if (browser == BrowserType.Chrome)
            {
                //"Chrome_WidgetWin_1"

                Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
                foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
                {
                    // the chrome process must have a window
                    if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                    //         new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"));
                    // find the automation element
                    AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);

                    // manually walk through the tree, searching using TreeScope.Descendants is too slow (even if it's more reliable)
                    AutomationElement elmUrlBar = null;
                    try
                    {
                        // walking path found using inspect.exe (Windows SDK) for Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m (currently the latest stable)
                        var elm1 = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Google Chrome"));
                        var elm2 = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetLastChild(elm1); // I don't know a Condition for this for finding :(
                        var elm3 = elm2.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ""));
                        var elm4 = elm3.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ToolBar));
                        elmUrlBar = elm4.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // Chrome has probably changed something, and above walking needs to be modified. :(
                        // put an assertion here or something to make sure you don't miss it
                        continue;
                    }

                    // make sure it's valid
                    if (elmUrlBar == null)
                    {
                        // it's not..
                        continue;
                    }

                    // elmUrlBar is now the URL bar element. we have to make sure that it's out of keyboard focus if we want to get a valid URL
                    if ((bool)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.HasKeyboardFocusProperty))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // there might not be a valid pattern to use, so we have to make sure we have one
                    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                    if (patterns.Length == 1)
                    {
                        string ret = "";
                        try
                        {
                            ret = ((ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0])).Current.Value;
                        }
                        catch { }
                        if (ret != "")
                        {
                            // must match a domain name (and possibly "https://" in front)
                            if (Regex.IsMatch(ret, @"^(https:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*$"))
                            {
                                // prepend http:// to the url, because Chrome hides it if it's not SSL
                                if (!ret.StartsWith("http"))
                                {
                                    ret = "http://" + ret;
                                }
                                return ret;
                            }
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code is working for me and get URL of active tab of chrome

```
 Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
            {
                // the chrome process must have a window
                if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // find the automation element
                AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);
                AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));

                // if it can be found, get the value from the URL bar
                if (elmUrlBar != null)
                {
                    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                    if (patterns.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Chrome URL found: " + val.Current.Value);
                        listbox.Items.Add(val.Current.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: For anyone looking to do this without including the localised text "Address and search bar", it (currently) works with `elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem recently with *System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys*
Compared to your result - it's 4 times faster, but doesn't work with websites which use **ctrl+l** hotkey  (for example StackOwerflow in edit mode). 
Depends on your needs :)

[image: Results]

```
 public void WithSendkeys()
    {
        AutomationElement.RootElement
            .FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"))
            .SetFocus();
        SendKeys.SendWait("^l");
        var elmUrlBar = AutomationElement.FocusedElement;
        var valuePattern = (ValuePattern) elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern);
        Console.WriteLine(valuePattern.Current.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
Condition condNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Novo separador");
AutomationElement elmNewTab = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condNewTab);
TreeWalker treewalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;

// IF THROWS A ERROR HERE, LOOK AT THE AutomationElement.NameProperty ("Novo separador") - PUT THIS TEXT IN APROPRIATE LANGUAGE
AutomationElement elmTabStrip = treewalker.GetParent(elmNewTab);
                                                                            
Condition condTabItem = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in elmTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condTabItem))
{
    // HERE IS YOUR TABS!!!!
    ret.Add(tabitem.Current.Name);
}
```