# check open URLs in chrome browser using VBA code

Tags: vba, google-chrome, vbscript

I am able to check open URLs in IE browser as in the code below. Does anyone have any idea how to check open URLs in chrome browser using VBA code?

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count

For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    Debug.Print my_url
    Debug.Print my_title
Next
```

Comment: VBA is not VB.NET - the words on both tags tell you so.

Comment: You'll need to use UIA to do this as far as I know. As far as I know, there isn't a DLL for accessing Chrome like this. Here is an example in C# that does what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516260/c-sharp-getting-chrome-urls-from-all-tab

Comment: Also, here is a video on getting started with UIA. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANTIGgs7YM4

Comment: https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/