# Proxy settings for .NET WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

I have looked everywhere for an answer and all I found was confusing-incomplete bits.

The best way I found was to modify the registry like so:

```
string key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";

string serverName = "";//your proxy server name;

string port = ""; //your proxy port;

string proxy = serverName + ":" + port;



RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);



RegKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxy);

RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
```

This works, but I need to also set the username and the password for the proxy.

I found that you can use the WebProxy class as this takes the credentials, but it doesn't work with WebBrowser.

So the other alternative would be to create an application-wide proxy where all http requests are routed thru it.

Anyone has any help on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a simple proxy in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend you use an [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) and a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). For more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control is exactly the same as Internet Explorer. They use the same proxy settings. Look up the WinINET API.