# implement a 80 http port listener

Tags: c#, http, sockets, desktop-application

I want to implement functionality similar to Fiddler.

I have tried 2 solutions:

HttpListener

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:80/");
listener.Start();
```

When `Start()` is executed I get the error:

> System.Net.HttpListenerException "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

which means that there is some other application listening on port 80 maybe IIS or whatever.

Sockets

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 80);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

 // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
 try
 {
     listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
// .....
```

When `listener.Bind()` is executed I get:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

which means the same thing, there is already another application listening on port 80.

So how does Fiddler listen to port 80 without these problems?
I would prefer to use a class like HttpListener because it's higher level instead of a lower level class like socket where I have to implement the HTTP Protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how does Fiddler listen to port 80 without these problems?

Fiddler is not accepting *incoming* connections on port 80 - it is acting as a proxy for *outgoing* HTTP connections. Some other application is using port 80 on your machine, so it is blocked for usage since there can only be one listener on a given port (in this case IIS as you mention in the comments).

Comment: You are right. I wrote code for incoming connections. I want to write code for outgoing connections like Fiddler. Can you give me a clue how to do that?

Comment: There's some good info on how to create a proxy in this SO thread which should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c

Answer (score 1):

That means something else is listening on port 80.  You'll have to exit that application before yours will work.

Comment: Skype or a local web server are the main culprits for this

Comment: You don't understand. Yes, there is another application probably IIS. But Fiddler works without any problem. How can I do it too?

Comment: @PaulRusu I believe that fiddler works as an extension for the browser. If you only want it to work with 1 browser, this is fine, otherwise you will have to re-write parts of your code several times for each browser. The alternative is to sniff for packets on the network with WinPCAP, but this wont work for any website using https://

Comment: @AndrewBrock pretty sure fiddler isn't a browser extension *as such* - it may have some hooks (in particular for SSL), but primarily it is lower level than that