# Issue WebRequest while reading NetworkStream of TcpListener

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, httpwebrequest

Following on from the post [How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c) I have been playing around with implementing a basic proxy.

Where I am getting stuck and confused is trying to issue a `WebRequest` with the information provided in the original request.

Using the following code.

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

(webRequest as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
webRequest.Method = "GET";

WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
byte[] responseBytes = responseStream.ReadFully();
```

I can successfully issue a request and return the page content.

However when I put it inside a Proxy request (IE: `TcpListener`) like such.

```
TcpListener _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
this._listener.Start();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while (true)
{
    TcpClient client = this._listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
    int i = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    while (i != 0)
    {
        string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
        RequestHeader header = new RequestHeader(data.ToUpper());
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(header.URL);
        (webRequest as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = header.UserAgent;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse(); //It gets here and never returns
        Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] responseBytes = responseStream.ReadFully();
        networkStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        i = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    client.Close();
}
```

It blocks at the line `WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();` and never returns.

This has definitely got nothing to do with the data provided by the `RequestHeader` class I created as I've also tried hardcoding the values.

I'm assuming I'm missing something fundamental about the way sockets work in such a scenario and the approach required. Hopefully someone can clarify for me.

Comment: What assembly does contain the `RequestHeader` class?

Comment: Sorry If I haven't been clear enough, its a custom class designed to parse the header, if you're trying to replicate this I suggest just hardcoding the values.

Comment: [1] Did you check while debugging if header.URL is correct, and indeed the one sent by the proxy client? [2] The machine where you are running this code - is it directly connected to internet or is accessed thru proxy/corporate-firewall? Check your IE settings to determine that, you may have to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: @PrahladYeri You were on the right track. It was a proxy issue. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: Good that you were able to solve it. Such configuration "gotchas" are quite common in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be a proxy issue.

Basically for testing I needed to set the machine proxy to 127.0.0.1:1234 or similar.

This in turn was being used in the default settings when initializing a `WebRequest`.

So all I needed to do in the end was the following to bypass the proxy.

```
(webRequest as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = header.UserAgent;
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Proxy = null; //Adding this line cleared the proxy.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are assuming you have read all the header.

Instead of this, some kind of state machine should be implemented to parse the incoming HTTP-request. The state machine must collect the information about the request and, of course, detect the **end of request**, then you process the request (proxy stuff) and send the response. Just Google **C# http state machine** for examples.