# Parental control or web filter with c#

Tags: c#, controls

It is possible that such a program written with C #?
if yes how we can?
If you have links or information on this I say thank you.

Comment: [check it out, a LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: @cmbasnett not really, because it looks like that someone marked it for favorite question.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow isn't here to do your work and research for you. Put some effort in man. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you'd probably be looking at setting up a proxy on your local network, pointing the machines you want parental control on to that proxy, and filtering the "allowed" traffic by either:

- Checking website address against a predefined blocklist, 
  and/or
- Reading through the HTML looking for *naughty* words or phrases.

[How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c) has a fair bit of detail about setting up a proxy in C#.

Also found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92512/Writing-a-Parental-Control-Software-for-Windows. An old project but might be worth looking at if you're researching a project like this.

Comment: thank you James Crawshaw for you're help. i want to learn create proxy and Starting it from begining.

Comment: Good luck! Whilst you're coding it, post your programming related questions on StackOverflow and I'm sure the community will be willing to help. Generally though, it's better to post questions regarding specific coding problems rather than a more open ended general question such as this one, with no _correct_ answer.

Comment: thank's but how to control and send all received and send packet from all Browser to proxy?