# Hide url in a javascript popup in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm using Mozilla firefox and I need to hide the URL from the popup I'm using location=no,directories=no but it's still showing

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_login" runat="server" Text="Login" Width="105px" style="height: 26px" onClientclick = "javascript:window.open('login_page.aspx','name','height=299, width=477,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,about:blank'); return false;" />
```

How can I fix it?

thank you

Comment: For security reason, modern browsers do not allow hiding the address bar in popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of popup you can use jquery dialog and besides browser block popup windows these days

```
$('<div></div>').dialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of windows and iframes is always public for security reasons. If you really want to hide the location and present the content as coming from your own site, you need to set up a proxy on your network that passes on the requests to the actual server. See [How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)