# Monitor requests and responses for a WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, request, browser, response

I have a program that contains a `WebBrowser` control.
And i need to navigate the browser to some site urls.This site execute some javascripts code and send requests to the server and get response.I need to know what they send and what they get because i need to work with them.Exactly something like `Fiddler` do.
What should i do for this?

Comment: Fiddler Core? Or write proxy code yourself...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, not entire Fiddler core, only monitoring responses and requests.I need to implement this myself

Comment: If you don't want to use Fiddler Core - go ahead with writing own proxy (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c is possible starting point). Than configure browser to use your proxy and enjoy the results.

Comment: You can also register a [pluggable protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743(v=vs.85).aspx) for HTTP and/or HTTPS to intercept the traffic. With some efforts, it can be written in C#.