# Is it possible to change script running clientside on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

So I'm playing a game online on my laptop and it is a pretty simple html5 game but the optimization is nonexistant. The game with a few circles on my screen is using 85% of my cpu.

Logically, I started profiling the game and was trying to figure out if I could optimize it for my laptop. Now, what I'm wondering is how could I run the game but with a tweaked version of the JS script that is running.

If I try to save the page and run it from my laptop it of course has CORS issues so I can not access the server.

Can I somehow change the script a bit which is executing in my browser but while still staying "inside the webpage" which is running so that I may normally make XHR requests to the server?

Also, although this is not in the title of the question, can I somehow proxy the XHR request to my script but while not breaking the CORS rule?

Why is it so different if I run the same thing from my browser and from a saved HTML on my desktop? I have the same IP and am doing the same thing but from the url it "feels like" I'm running it from somewhere else. Can I somehow imitate that I'm running "from the webpage" but instead run it from a modified saved html?

Comment: What do you mean with "locally"? Your browser is local too and the javascript as well..

Comment: Thats what confuses me. I'm lacking the terminology but not sure where to find it. I'll edit the question

Comment: You are not the first and probably not the last that has come to this site asking how to "modify" the code for agar.io.  This is not a hacking site, we can't tell you how to modify someone else's source, or how to stop them from detecting your "modifications".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **could** proxy, given there isn't a cross domain protection mechanism or some sort of logging in (which complicates stuff).

What you could very well do is use a browser extension which allows you to **add** CSS, HTML and JavaScript.

I'm not entirely savvy on extensions so I'm not sure you can **modify** existing code but I'm guessing that if you can **add** arbitrary JS code you may very well replace the script tag containing the game for a similar personally modified script based on it. It's worth a try...

[Link to getting started with chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

***Update:***

If you're set on doing it, proxying ammounts to requesting an URL with your application and do something with the page (html) instead of the original source. I assume you want to change the page and serve it to your browser.

With this in mind you will need the following, I dont know C# so you'll have to google around for libraries and utilities:

- a way to request **URL**s (see link at bottom)
- a way to modify the page, you need a ***DOM crawler***
- a way to start said process and serve it to your browser by hitting your own URL, meaning you need some sort of **web server**

[I found the following question specifically on proxying with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on where to start reading about proxying? I would actually like to figure out how to maybe proxy this to a C# application. I'm mostly confused as to how the whole identification of who's actually running the code is done and how to do some pretending