# How do I create simple web proxy server using C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, proxy, httpwebresponse

I have requirement of having proxy server where request from browser will be forwarded to my custom proxy server. Afterwards Proxy server will read request from client and talk to requested resource using some thing like this --

HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("http://www.google.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

then once I have response back in response object write returned HTML to browser , at this point I am stuck and do not know how to write information to browser ?

Can someone please help ???

Comment: Which framework are you using? Web forms? Are you doing this from within a aspx page?

Comment: no its plain , console application. Here is flow, I will have a proxy server running as console application. I have changed firefox browser setting to point to my custom proxy server, so whenever browser request any url request will be first of all forwarded to my custom proxy server which in turn should talk to URL and return response to browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a simple proxy in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)