# (Selenium) C# Tunnel / Proxy - Corporate network access from external

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, routes, automated-tests

I am wondering if anyone has any information around how to create a Proxy/Tunnel on an internal corporate network which can then be accessed via a machine on say, AWS to access the internal networks websites etc.

The specific use case here is that I wish to host a Selenium Grid instance internal to the network, but I wish to have the Selenium Nodes sitting in the Amazon AWS Cloud. (Scalability).
However, the websites we want to test are internal and I don't think we will have the flexibility to open ports etc to allow access.

I used a product called 'CrossBrowserTesting.com' - which had a neat feature which allowed the external nodes, to resolve internal websites, via a proxy that existed within the web browser of the CrossBrowserTesting.com browsing session.

I would ideally like something similar, but to be using our own AWS Hosted machines.

Does anyone have any experience with using Selenium in such a model
Eg:

Tests execute on External nodes, but test against an internal hosted website.

Ideally - I would like all of the configuration to be accomplished using C# code where possible.
Eg:
Can the test spin up a Proxy/Relay internally which then punches through to the external node, to allow network access / name resolution?

Any tips or links to similar solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: [Have you tried creating a simple proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c)? The question had a couple of [C# based proxy solutions](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy).

Comment: I was actually experimenting with creating a simple proxy. I was hoping there was an out of the box solution available - but for free etc.
The simple proxy I made was able to route http traffic, but seemed to have difficulty with SSL content. I don't know if a simple proxy will be able to handle all the SSL secured content/css/js files etc that many websites tend to have in their header section.

Comment: Selenium can run on Docker now which can have the [proxy setup](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Corporate-Proxies) in the docker file.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help with the setup I am going for.
The machine that selenium will be running on will not have direct access to our test environment. We will need to have a reverse proxy of sorts in order to serve internal website/environment content to the external box.