# How to make web GET request from server with no internet access, using another server as proxy (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, proxy, webclient

I have a C# application running on Windows Server (Server A).  That server has no internet access due to firewall restrictions.

I can access another server on the same network that does have internet access (Server B).

Using C#, how can I make a GET request to the internet from A, using B as some kind of proxy?  Would this require anything to be set up on B to facilitate this, or can I just do it somehow using WebClient?

Comment: You will need to set up something on B. Something like this: [How to create a simple proxy in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c).

Comment: You need to execute your code on server B, or use it as a web proxy. But this sounds like an X-Y problem. Why are you trying to make an HTTP request from a server which is restricted from doing so? Have you had approval from the security team who set the restrictions? Why has server B got internet access if server A hasn’t? Has a threat analysis been done on Server A connecting to the internet, even via a proxy? Presumably it has been isolated for a reason..

Comment: @stuartd - yes, all good points, the suggestion to use B as a proxy came from the network security admin (who is also responsible for restricting internet access on A).  No idea why he wanted it doing like this, but that's what he said.  Unfortunately he didn't elaborate on the specifics of how to set it up