# How to Bypass CefSharp and libcef to handle POST request Manually?

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am new to "Web Programming" and I would like to know if it is possible to handle POST request and response manually in CEFSharp.
The Scenario is that the website that I am interacting with using CEFSharp is creating the request, But I want to take control after that if it is possible. I Imagine that ResourceRequestHandler must be some thing like the follwing, which one must convert the CEFSharp IRequest to .NET HttpRequestMessage somehow:

```
public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.ResourceRequestHandler
{
private static readonly HttpClient hc = new();
private readonly AutoResetEvent are;

public CustomResourceRequestHandler(AutoResetEvent are)
{
    this.are = are;
}

protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
{
    var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, request.Url);
    
    //How to add Headers properly?
    foreach (string rh in request.Headers)
        hrm.Headers.Add(rh, request.Headers[rh]);
    
    //How to add content properly?
    
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async() =>
    {
        are.WaitOne();
        var response = hc.SendAsync(hrm);
        await response;
        // Do Something with response.Result
    });

    return CefReturnValue.Cancel;
}
}
```

The questions are: First, Is this even possible? since the underlying socket is changed, doesn't the webserver complain? Second, How to copy IRequest to HttpRequestMessage Properly? I Added the headers, and don't know if it's done correctly, But I am struggling to convert the content field. Third, Is copying Headers and Content enough?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of using httpclient to make the request?

Comment: @amaitland Awsome work on CEFSharp library BTW. I am doing a time critical task and want to do time profiling. I want to log the time network packets hit the wire(or network card driver) and the exact time the response packets are received. I will replace the HttpRequest with raw sockets next. CEFSharp is crafting the correct request for me.

Comment: Have you checked the performance metrics available thru DevTools? You should be able to access those metrics programatically https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance/ https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3165

Comment: Otherwise I think you'd be better off using/writing a proxy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with CEFSharp and .NET HttpRequest, this is a semi-working example. I had to copy Cookies, Headers, and Content to make it work. Calling are.Set() will trigger the manual request and reading response. Before going for something like this, check @amailand comments in question which may suggest better methods for you.

```
protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async() =>
        {
            //Cookies
            var cm = chromiumWebBrowser.GetCookieManager();
            var t = cm.VisitUrlCookiesAsync(request.ReferrerUrl, true);
            Task.WaitAll(t);
            var cookies = t.Result;

            var cc = new CookieContainer();
            using HttpClientHandler hch = new() 
            { 
                CookieContainer = cc, 
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };
            using HttpClient hc = new(hch);

            foreach (var cookie in cookies)
                cc.Add(new System.Net.Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));

            var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, request.Url);
            
            //Headers
            foreach (string rh in request.Headers)
                hrm.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(rh, request.Headers[rh]);

            //Check if more headers should be added manually

            //Content
            hrm.Content = new StringContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request.PostData.Elements[0].Bytes),
                Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            are.WaitOne();
            var response = hc.SendAsync(hrm);
            await response;

            if (response.Result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) return;
            var t1 = response.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            Task.WaitAll(t1);
            // result is in t1.Result
        });

        return CefReturnValue.Cancel;
    }
```